# i want to write a c# program using array list nos

Tags: c#-4.0

I am new in programming in c#, i want to write a program in c# that result will like below i have mentioned so could any one please help me how to write this.

i am trying to writing like this. but how we replace the character with * from certain position.

```
 for(int i=1; i<51; i++ )
   {
   Console.WriteLine(i);  
   }

     1
     *
     3
     4
     *
     6
     7
     8
     9
     *
     11
     12
     13
     14
     15
     16
     *
     and so on 
     50
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement.

Comment: sorry matthew, can you write something how do i do.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement in FOR loop.

> ArrayList ItemList = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
> For(int i=0;i<50;i++)
> {      
> Itemlist=Console.ReadLine(); //Give your input to populate values in arraylist
> }
>
> Foreach(var o in ItemList) { Console.WriteLine(o); }
> ```